# Why does TimeSpan.FromMinutes return incorrect total hours value

Tags: c#, timespan

When I run this on .netfiddle I expected a result of 182 hours hours and 30 minutes.  But instead I get 183 hours - why is this?  It's as if daylight saving had happened?

```
TimeSpan tsTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)10950);
Console.WriteLine(tsTime.TotalHours.ToString("00") + ":" + tsTime.Minutes.ToString("00"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 30 minutes is 0.5 hour so when you are converting it using `ToString()` its make it as full hour. So rounding it can solve the problem

If you want rounded output then round it as which give you `182:30`

```
TimeSpan tsTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)10950);
Console.WriteLine(((int)tsTime.TotalHours).ToString("00") + ":" + tsTime.Minutes.ToString("00"));
```

and if you want actual then it will give `182.5:30`

```
Console.WriteLine(tsTime.TotalHours+ ":" + tsTime.Minutes);
```

Comment: The Math.Round doesn't work if you add 10 minutes to the original minutes. It will give 183:40 but expected result is 182:40

Answer (score 0):

It's because of rounding.

You are outputting a double value via `ToString` with a formatting that rounds them to integer values according to the standard rules so .5 rounds up to the next integer value.

If you examine the actual value you'll see that it is 182.5 as you expected.

```
 Console.WriteLine(tsTime.TotalHours.ToString() + ":" + tsTime.Minutes.ToString());
```

outputs

> 182.5:30

You need to truncate the value to get the total number of whole hours (and you can lose the `.ToString` as the values are integers

```
 Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(tsTime.TotalHours) + ":" + tsTime.Minutes);
```

or even:

```
 Console.WriteLine((int)tsTime.TotalHours + ":" + tsTime.Minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        TimeSpan tsTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)10950);
        Console.WriteLine(((int)tsTime.TotalHours).ToString("00") + ":" + tsTime.Minutes.ToString("00"));
```

Output:

> 182:30